# c++: array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to c++ and I have a question about the array of pointers. In the following program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char b[10];
    char* a[10]; 
    b[0] = 'b';
    a[0] = &b[0];
    cout << a[0] << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

a is an array of pointers pointing to char objects. a[0] is then assigned the address of b[0], but why the cout result is a c-string `b` rather than the its address ? I thought a[0] should be storing a pointer. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: ",,,rather than the its address?" - to cout a  "char*" address, static cast the char* to  void*,  i.e.  "cout << static_cast<void*>(a[0]) << endl;"

Comment: `std::cout <<` operator has overload that takes `const char*`, to print null-terminated `c-string's`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `a[0]` has a type of `char *`.

The `<<` operator, when give a value of `char *`, interprets it as a `'\0'` terminated text string, and that's what you see. That's how it works.

Just by the luck of the draw, the second char of `b`, `b[1]`, turned out to be a binary zero, which serves perfectly as a '\0', however this is undefined behavior, and is technically a bug (a.k.a. [a nasal demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` reads c-string and print that when `char*` is passed.

`a[0]` is `char*` and pointer is stored there.

Therefore, the data `b` in the array `b` is read and printed.

To have `std::cout` print addresses, cast the addresses to `void*` like `cout << (void*)a[0] << endl;`.

Also note that what is in the array `b` is not c-string because it is not null-terminated. `b[1] = '\0';` should be added before `cout << a[0] << endl;`.

Answer (score 2):

> but why the cout result is a c-string b rather than the its address ?

Because pointers to characters are handled differently than all other pointer types are handled by character streams: They are required to be pointers to null terminated string, and content of that string will be printed. In other words, the behaviour is as if `%s` format specifier was used with `printf`.

This is in order to make following program work as one might expect:

```
const char* str = "Hello, World!";
std::cout << str; // expected output is Hello, World!
                  // expected output is not an address
```

---

In your program the array `a` is not guaranteed to be null terminated because you didn't initialise any element to be the null character. As such, the pre-condition is not necessarily satisfied in which case the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I thought a[0] should be storing a pointer.

`a[0]` is a pointer.